# Visual Basic.NET Training Example

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

We'll soon have some high school kids here in our company for some training lessons in programming for about 1 1/2 days.

We decided to do Visual Basic.NET and thought about programming a little calculator with the four basic operators.

Considering the fact that they will be here for only 1 1/2 days, this application might be "too" complex to be taught in this time range.

Do you have any ideas of what else can be taught in such a short time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say 1.5days for a calculator by a complete novice is about spot on actually.

You could set the task as a simple 4-operator to be a target.  If they surpass this they can add more complex functions.  If not then it could simply be just for adding for example.  The complexity is expandable depending on the student.

Comment: Good point, it is a simple project that can easily be scaled back or expanded based on how quickly the students progress.

Comment: I think I will go with the calculator then. One Form with two Textboxes and the four operation buttons. (A MessageBox returns the result)

Answer (score 1):

Simplefied version, only plus and minus. Or a leet/1337 translator, only requires them to do:

```
newBox.Text = oldBox.Text.Replace("l", "1").Replace("e", "3").Replace("t", "7")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think the calculator would be doable.  Your basically only doing a simple form with some buttons and some basic logic on the various click events for the operators.  Only issue would be the logic for chaining the operands and operators.

You might want to do a trial run by yourself of the project, and think where you would break it into steps to explain and such and see how long it takes.

Comment: Parsing the string can be harsh, and dividing the view (textbox/label) and the actual vars can be confusing).

Answer (score 0):

Rock Paper scissors game? This would be good for if statements... Then if they grasp that the concept of conditional statements you could move on to a select case example. I find once most people understand that programs are based on conditions they generally can grasp much of the more advanced concepts much quicker. Conditional circuts were after all the beginning of computing.

Answer (score 0):

When I was at school I started off by building a simple application that has a few buttons and on click it changes the background colour. Then you add more functionality such as a message box, then maybe a button that closes the applicaiton. Talk to them about the debugger/compiler and explain to them how it is very similar to making a cake with all the ingredients (I wish somebody explained it to me like that back then). You can make it as simple or as complicated as you want. Or instead of a real calculator you can teach them how to create a Reverse Polish Notation calculator (i.e in order to add 5 to 3 you would click: 5 then 3 then + which will return 8. Anyway trying not to get carried away here. Good luck and most important of all: make it fun for the future generation of programmers"